# Adsense Ads not visible in Brave Browser

Tags: google-adsense, google-ads

Recently learnt that the Brave Browser, which is gaining steady popularity, is cutting off all Google Ads. It is obviously a loss to the webmasters and site publishers.

Is there a way to detect a site being accessed by Brave browser, and display a suitable message to access the site from another browser which does not block ads?

Looking for an answer that fits for PHP site.

PS: Brave does not even show up as a "Browser" in Google Analytics. Completely cut-off.

Comment: There appear to be several answers here on Stack Overflow: [How do I tell if a user is using Brave as their browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523448/how-do-i-tell-if-a-user-is-using-brave-as-their-browser)